# JavaScript factorial

Tags: javascript, factorial

Cant wrap my head around **arguments.callee** and why truefactorial = 120. Some help would be much appreciated

```
    function factorial(num){
        if (num <= 1) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return num * arguments.callee(num-1)
        }
    }

    var trueFactorial = factorial;

    factorial = function(){
        return 0;
    };

    alert(trueFactorial(5));   //120
```

Comment: What don't you understand specifically?

Comment: Because `5! = 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 120`. That's how the factorial is defined.

Comment: *After edit:* `arguments.callee` is just a fancy (and deprecated) way to refer to the function itself: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee . Do you have any questions beyond what's explained in the MDN documentation?

Comment: @SterlingArcher I think that was just an attempt to demonstrate what was confusing.

Comment: This is an example of recursion.  I suggest looking up other code for factorial, and tracing it out on paper.  Try drawing the recursion tree.  This is the only way for me I ever could gain understanding of recursion.

Comment: It looks like the point of this snippet is to show that if you use callee instead of the function directly, you can redefine the function factorial and the original function will still work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside a function, `arguments.callee` refers to that function.

So `factorial` is recursive - it calls itself.  No matter what name you might use for it.

Redefining the name `factorial` to reference a different function has no affect on the first definition, because nowhere in that first definition does it use the name `factorial`.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments [`arguments.callee` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee#Description) and you should not use it (it won't even work if your code is running in strict mode). However, if you replace `arguments.callee` with `factorial` in your example, the end result will not do anything useful:

```
function factorial(num){
    if (num <= 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return num * factorial(num-1);
    }
}

var trueFactorial = factorial;

factorial = function(){
    return 0;
};

alert(trueFactorial(5));   // 0
```

This is because `factorial` gets reassigned before your function is called, and when it ultimately tries to call `factorial()` inside the function, the new `factorial()` just produces a 0.

There is a way around this, and that is to use a named function expression:

```
var factorial = function factorial (num) {     //   <--- This line
    if (num <= 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return num * factorial(num-1);
    }
}

var trueFactorial = factorial;

factorial = function(){
    return 0;
};

alert(trueFactorial(5));   // 120  (Yay!)
```

If you do this, even if the `factorial` variable is reassigned outside of the function, it will keep its original meaning inside the function, and will not break.